# Exclude the first 'n' number of posts of a tag from home page?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, exclude, offsets

**Use case (example):** Using a separate, custom query my website's home page shows 5 featured posts, tagged 'Highlights (highlights)', followed by the latest posts, from the main query.

I don't want the 5 featured posts, i.e. the first 5 posts tagged 'highlights', to appear among the latest posts.

To put it another way, the latest posts should include all the latest posts, but in doing so, if it finds a post is tagged 'highlights' and is among the first 5, it should be excluded.

All this, without breaking the pagination.

How do I do this?

---

I have faint idea as to how I can do this:

```
function itsme_filtered_latest_posts( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( ... );

        $query->set( 'offset', ... );

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'itsme_filtered_latest_posts' );
```

Like I said, I only have a faint idea, which is as good as having none.

Answer (score 0):

A in your example, you have access to all the WP_Query Object query_vars (see [here])[1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Example_WP_Query_Object), you could use the `post__not_in` query_var in your query. It takes an array of ids as a parameter. So first you query for your posts tagged 'highlighted'. 
While displaying them, you would add all their ids to an array like so

```
<?php
$do_not_duplicate = array(); // set befor loop variable as an array

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; // remember ID's of 'highlighted' posts

    //display posts

endwhile;
?>
```

then you kick off another query like so.

```
<?php
// another loop without duplicates
query_posts( array(
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate
    )
);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // display your posts without the highlighted
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
function get_custom_posts_wpse_124312() {
  static $post_qry;
  if (!empty($post_qry)) {
    return $post_qry;
  } else {
    $post_qry = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=>2)); // whatever arguments you need
  }
  return $post_qry;
}

function filter_featured_special_wpse_124312($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query()) { // whatever conditions you need
    remove_action('pre_get_posts','filter_featured_special_wpse_124312');
    $fs = get_custom_posts_wpse_124312();
    if (!empty($fs)) {
      $ids = wp_list_pluck($fs->posts,'ID');
      $qry->set('posts__not_in',$ids);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','filter_featured_special_wpse_124312');
```

The `get_custom_posts_wpse_124312()` should retrieve your "5 featured posts, tagged 'Highlights (highlights)'" using whatever arguments you need to do that. I assume a `tax_query`? You then use that data to exclude the posts returned from your main query. You can then use `get_custom_posts()` in your template to retrieve the post object for display. You will need to create a Loop for it in the template file. Because `$post_qry` is static the "featured" query should only run once.